# How can i create a strict Exclude utility type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Background**

I've been using the `Exclude` and `Extract` utility types but have come across a case where i only want to match exact types not subtypes.

**So far**

I've managed to create a `StrictExtract` utility type that only extracts types that are an exact match - although there's possibly an easier way to do this?

```
type StrictExtract<T, U> =
    T extends unknown ? 
        U extends T ?
            T extends U ? 
                T : 
                never : 
            never :
        never;
```

**Examples**

```
type objOne = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

type objTwo = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: Function;
}
```

```
type ext1 = Extract<objOne | objTwo | string | number, string | number | objOne>
// string | number | objOne | objTwo

type stext1 = StrictExtract<objOne | objTwo | string | number, string | number | objOne>
// string | number | objOne
```

So where as `Extract` would also  match `objTwo` as it's a subtype of `objOne`, `StrictExtract` accepts the same type parameters, but only extracts exact type matches.

So `StrictExclude` would mirror the input parameters of `Exclude<Type, Union>`, but would only exclude types that where an exact match.

```
type excl = Exclude<objOne | objTwo | string | number, objOne | string | number>
// never

type strExcl = StrictExclude<objOne | objTwo | string | number, objOne | string | number>
// should result in objTwo
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=72&ssc=27&pln=68&pc=1#code/LAKFEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrABASRgl6B5STAb1AwowAd4B7KgRgC4MBnaeKAcwG5zKa9AEwtIAVwC2AIwR8QAX1ARcSNJhxxV6ACoB3WhlgAPOJAAmrbCvywipfhUFUAzCwBiYyKmjhakOYpgIKgANsislgCyAJ4AwmERdhjgElQhsBKwMJYaeGpJZCCU1HSMLOyckFwYALwYAORw7PVyxU4iGOLSCLUYDAFKwQlRccN6BsamFhgx8eGsSSlpGVnQOdZq4xiFDiX0rhgeXj5+vQAUAJS1AHzb8gNBofMzo-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-sRDn6ZJhmsWZfnSd8bF+RZ8BWXkOj6EpxJjAFcUcTJTkYIg4A9ppHnad5flPolUkJQZwViflrDhem5mubFlUUph3Hhvhv6hGIZiwCm6ZZr0jb5uYljFqW5ZthgZytk2vUYPWw3dbW1ZVmc0C0EWLDaJitytiwZxiEYLAZqtE1XBtYhCNtmZ7StHadN2Q5vmORihJOd0hC1bWifeq4JUht6wumr3rlByGHmeIDMcQ-Y3aacb3e5BGec1rUkehb0vgYf1mgDEFoXln0wQgQPMaw7zkiEZgYF8rBiCE0DJOi720HVo5sOARiZTDkNPfDPklUV+gVblvnGYxdmIYTFMkzIl1g-VmAqj2CqRlpj3PUmnOhQLH1Qbzxl5dztCxQTRNi9LUEpbA4BcO8VPQ017NtSrgVqyjoFcJrwy2fjIvExg4vYzrKWQFAmBW7DNvK3zXNBerZou28MVC2wHuG07quu8QgxAA)

**Problem**

I've tried to use the same approach to work out the logic for `StrictExclude` but have been going round in circles for a while now.

I started off with the following utility to get an understanding of what's output by each condition. I can see how to calculate which types need to be removed - essentially by using `StrictExtract` - but not how to then remove those exact types from the union of `T`... (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

```
type StrictExclude<T, U> =
    T extends unknown ?
        (U extends T ?
            (T extends U ?
                (tok: T) => U :
                (ux: U) => T) : 
            (u2x: U) => T) : 
        never;
```

**Question**

How do you create a strict exclude utility type, that only removes exact type matches, not subtypes?

Comment: If you want to deeply compare two types, use this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650

Comment: please provide test cases

Comment: Please put your use case examples in plain text and not just a playground link.  I don't understand why your tests for `StrictExclude` are testing something different for `StrictExtract`.  If the names are supposed to be semantically meaningful, I'd expect `StrictExtract<T, U> | StrictExclude<T, U>` to always be `T`... that is, any part of the union in `T` would appear in exactly one of `StrictExtract<T, U>` and `StrictExclude<T, U>`.  Is that a good expectation or do you mean something else by `StrictExclude`?  [This code](https://tsplay.dev/N5349W) implements such a dichotomy.

Comment: In your tests for `StrictExclude<T, U>` you put unions in `U` (and you didn't do this for `StrictExtract<T, U>`).  Can you articulate explicitly what you expect to see happen with unions in `U`?  I don't see why `StrictExclude<A | B, A | B>` would be `never` unless `A` and `B` are identical types, since you'd be checking `A` against `A | B` and `B` against `A | B`.  If you want to split all unions up, then you're checking `A` against `A`, `A` against `B`, `B` against `A`, and `B` against `B`, and you'd need to explain exactly how to combine those to produce the output type you want.

Comment: Hmm, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDzPOW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining how it works.  If not, please [edit] your question to demonstrate failing use cases.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, i was in a rush to pick up my daughter, i realise now the examples i gave where not great, so i've updated my question. For `StrictExclude` `U` can be a union, i've added an example above and in the playground link

Comment: @jcalz your final solution looks great, thanks a lot. An explanation of what's going on would be very much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it seems like you want `StrictExclude<T, U>` to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) across [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`, so if `T` is `A | B | C`, then `StrictExclude<A | B | C, U>` is equivalent to `StrictExclude<A, U> | StrictExclude<B, U> | StrictExclude<C, U>`.  So as a first step we can write this as a distributive conditional type:

```
type StrictExclude<T, U> = T extends unknown ? StrictExcludeInner<T, U> : never;
```

where
`StrictExcludeInner<T, U>` performs the desired operation on *non-union* types `T`.  The type `U` might still be a union, and we need to think carefully about what to do in this case.  The goal is to take (a non-union) `T` and compare it to each union element of `U`; if we find any such element where `T` and `U` are *mutually assignable* (so `T extends U` and `U extends T` are both true), then we want to return `never`.  On the other hand, if `T` is not mutually assignable with *any* union element of `U`, then we want to return `T`.  It is this "mutual assignability" that seems to be what you mean by "strict" in `StrictExclude`.

For example, assuming `D`, `E`, and `F` are distinct non-union types where no pair of them are mutually assignable, then `StrictExcludeInner<D, D | E>` should be `never`, but `StrictExcludeInner<F, D | E>` should be `F`.

We can write that like this:

```
type _StrictExcludeInner<T, U> = 0 extends (
    U extends T ? [T] extends [U] ? 0 : never : never
) ? never : T;
```

Let's first examine the middle chunk of that:

```
U extends T ? [T] extends [U] ? 0 : never : never
```

This is a distributive conditional type in `U`. (I have suppressed the distributivity over unions in `T` by writing `[T] extends [U]` instead of `T extends U`, but since we expect `T` not to be a union, then it doesn't really matter.)  Each union element of `U` which is mutually assignable with `T` will end up contributing a `0` to the final type, and each element of `U` which is not mutually assignable with `T` will end up contributing a `never` to the final type.  Since `0 | never` is `0`, then `U extends T ? [T] extends [U] ? 0 : never : never` will evaluate to `0` if and only if at least one element of `U` is mutually assignable with `T`.  Otherwise it will evaluate to `never`.

So now let's look at the full type of `StrictExcludeInner<T, U>`.  If `U` has at least one element that mutually assigns with `T`, then it will evaluate to `0 extends (0) ? never : T`... since `0 extends 0` is true, this will evaluate to `never`, as desired.  On the other hand, if `U` has no elements that mutually assign with `T`, then it will evaluate to `0 extends (never) ? never : T`.  Since `0 extends never` is false, this will evaluate to `T`, also as desired.

---

Okay, let's test it on your examples:

```
type strExcl = StrictExclude<objOne | objTwo | string | number, objOne | string | number> // objTwo

type six = StrictExclude<MyClassOne | MyClassTwo, MyClassOne | MyClassTwo> // never
type seven = StrictExclude<MyClassOne | MyClassTwo | string, MyClassOne | MyClassTwo> // string
type eight = StrictExclude<MyClassOne | MyClassTwo | string, MyClassOne> // string | MyClassTwo
type nine = StrictExclude<MyClassOne | MyClassTwo | string, MyClassTwo> //  string | MyClassOne
```

These all evaluate to the types you expected. Hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#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-GrHSgAPoAZQqPgAokYwqIzBB0HgoAAebQAGmQAFUbjUAAyGEzZaanZEF8tTSzaZAAfmQAG1tABdOuVyytgtdltlkQQABuCOHY6gJEuLbwk+QTG0sgdmpQcfYieToVTEBz+aL3Ubkx7yC8AGsQNRdFiW7H42Akym0xnoHvCzcJ7btpGWMAjN112ATcn13WZRkKAAfElRnGfMwPmOwoPgyJxhuAB6NDYVHaAVydFUxwVQDgO3NMs2Q5hIOgt59GQKDvWBODXiSRCqJQ-R0Mw+iOFwlAIGADh3jAAD70fEjQKYiiWPIzY6LNDhGNJSSIA4ulKiQiTxh42FQBQGoiIfLcdzIiTKOkmjZPpBSYPY5AMLILjaNYpT+i0wFROEjcDJArMXUol0ZNU4FHPZaB818liHKgkKoBU-z9BIIA)

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this and also give a thorough explanation of how it works, it's very much appreciated :)